# Pygame Display.Update() Fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

When programming in Python 3, using Pygame, there is a problem with updating portions of the screen on Mac OS.

For example:

```
import pygame
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
screen.fill((100,100,100))
pygame.display.update(0,0,100,200)
```

This should display a screen half grey and half white, however, on Mac OS it updates the whole screen, making it all grey, as if I had written:

```
pygame.display.update(0,0,200,200)
```

Or

```
pygame.display.update()
```

Or

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

This can be a huge problem in developing optimised programs. If all I need to do is update one pixel, Pygame will update the whole screen and waste too much time doing it.

This has been a problem for years, as far as I can tell. I feel it has never been recognised and due to it many programs are poorly optimised or never finished.

I know this is a problem with Pygame itself, so does anyone know of any kind of fix or way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: i suspect if there was a fix it would have been mainlined already, do you know if this is a generic pygame bug or a platform specific one? i.e. does it only affect macos? or windows and linux too?

Comment: note, just tested this under python3.4 on winxp with the result described above

Comment: having had a quick look at the pygame source, it looks to me like it's expecting a single argument containing the rect to be updated. on windows changing `pygame.display.update(0,0,100,200)` to `pygame.display.update((0,0,100,200))` gave me a window with half grey and half black...

Comment: @JamesKent Just tried pygame.display.update((0,0,100,200)) and the window is still all grey :'(. I think this is specific to MacOS, but it may also affect linux too. I appreciate your tests.

Comment: on Linux I get half grey and half black screen

Comment: I encountered the same presumed bug and found a work-around that works for me on MacOS Mojave (10.14) on a Macbook Air from 2014:
After the update(), simply add "pygame.event.get()" 
Don't ask me why, but for me it triggers the update; without it: light grey screen.

Comment: @PatrixHume31 The window is still all grey on Windows 10 too.